# Setting up Server Side and Client Side for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: tomcat7, client-side, ibm-mobilefirst, server-side, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make 2 applications which uses Google Cloud Messaging.

My goal is to make a one application Android IBM Worklight which can receive Push notifications (CLIENT-SIDE) and another application a Tomcat Server Java Servlet (SERVER-SIDE).

However, I have absolutely no experience in using Google Cloud Messaging and it is my first time using Android IBM Worklight as client-side.

So I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction that I so could have 1st application using tomcat server sending the Push notifications (SERVER-SIDE) and another application using IBM Worklight as (CLIENT-SIDE) to receive the push notification.

I have been finding tutorials regarding this but I am stuck at implementation.

[This tutorial link](http://avilyne.com/?p=267) gave me an  idea on how to do server side since i am using tomcat server. However the client-side is code is not what I am looking for since I am using IBM Worklight inside.

[Another tutorial link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf) show me how the push notification works at IBM Worklight for both client and server side.  However, as mention earlier my server side is Tomcat server at Eclipse thus I think that I can't using this tutorial for server side.
As for client side, I think can use this tutorial since it is IBM Worklight however it is not using Google Cloud Messaging.

I would appreciate someone help me..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The second tutorial has the information you need.  If you have your Worklight server set up on Tomcat, just follow the tutorial and deploy the push adapter to that server.

Comment: Dhyuveter Hi there! After I read your comment, I realize I made a mistake. I did not specify that actually I have 2 applications. 1st application is IBM Worklight (CLIENT-SIDE) and Tomcat server (SERVER-SIDE). I hope that you now understood. Thanks!

Comment: You nee a Worklight server to use push notification.  Are you saying that the Worklight server is running on Tomcat?  or are you saying that some other server process that needs to trigger the push is running on Tomcat?  If the later, then that process running on Tomcat needs to make an http call to the Push adapter running on the Worklight server.  The details of how to invoke a Worklight adapter via HTTP can be found here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_adapter_invocation_service.html